# how to use geturl with an index.php in magento?

Tags: php, magento

the title may seem not clear. now this is my issues.
im using windows which is i need to run the magento with "index.php" on it.
**example** : "localhost/magentoproject/index.php/test/index/save"

now im using the getUrl function on form like this

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('test/index/save')?>
```

but after i inspect, the url shows like this

```
localhost/magentoproject/test/index/save
```

the url appear is not including the index.php, therefore, magento shows 404 not found.

how i solve this problem ? how to use geturl including the "index.php" on it.
currently im use the hardcode like this on the form

```
http://localhost/magentoproject/index.php/test/index/save
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to admin url of your site.
2. Next go to `System > configuration > web > Search` Engines Optimization
3. Then set `Use Web Server Rewrites` value to 'No'